# Hard to keep track which notification was clicked on from dropdown select menu

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, global-inbox

This issue seems to have started with the introduction to the new "follow" option. Before if we got pinged (@username), we'd see the notification appear in the dropdown select on the top left, and if we click the first notification or any single one, the other pings/notifications would stay in a colour that is "unvisited" (light gray).

But now, since I follow a few questions/answers, once I get notification (or pinged) and I click on the "one" or any notifications, all other notifications lose their grayish colour and it's hard to tell or follow which one(s) I did click on/visit from the dropdown menu. This has nothing to do with the "recent inbox messages" area/page, only the dropdown select.

I felt that this needed to be addressed. It's rather confusing.

---

Edit:

Here are a few screen captures and will explain them.

Here below is the first screen grab I took showing the number of notifications I received, from following questions and from being pinged by another member:

[image]

Then I bring up my notifications from the dropdown select showing the notifications in unvisited dark gray colour:

[image]

I then scrolled down to the end of the new notifications and chose the before last one and clicked on it:

[image]

This is the last image showing now all other notifications showing as if I clicked on them and it's hard to tell which one(s) I visited and didn't visit. Actually they all show as if I visited them:

[image]

- I hope that this is clear now.

---

What I did to replicate this was to follow a few more questions and have others ping me back and took the screen shots once I had enough to show you. This took a while but was able to replicate it.

Comment: The functionality of the inbox has not changed at all. If you close the inbox or leave or refresh the page, all other notifications lose their "new" status, because we don't store "read" status per-notification; we only store the last date you accessed the inbox. All we did was add additional notifications that can appear in the inbox.

Comment: @animuson Not the inbox per se but the dropdown menu. Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned "recent inbox messages". I'll remove it. Edit: I removed it.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you're talking about. You'll need to clarify with screenshots, even if the highlighting isn't there right now it's still helpful to visualize.

Comment: @animuson Yeah I know that it can be a bit hard to follow, sorry about that. I re-edited if that helps. I'll include screenshots once this happens again. Things sometimes happen too fast.

Comment: I pretty much *always* right-click or control-click on notifications to open them in a new tab. Left clicking replaces the current tab *and* means you have to go click the notification bar again to get to other messages (and if you've had many notifications, you may lose track, as described here)

Comment: @animuson I edited my post with images. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yes, that is your inbox. It is behaving exactly the same way as it always has. When you open the inbox, we update the last time you loaded it. When you open it again, everything before that date is displayed as read and everything after unread. We don't store a separate status per message.

Comment: @animuson Yes I know it's the inbox, but I am not talking about the "inbox" itself, but the way it's working now from just the dropdown select. Two different animals here :)) However, if this should be a feature request to make unvisited comments/pings/followed posts, let me know if I should ask for it to be done that way, to make the notifications we didn't visit yet, to be set in a colour that tells / shows us we didn't go there yet.

Comment: I'm aware of what it is. I'm clarifying that it is not a bug, it has literally always worked that way. You can make a feature request for it, but it's unlikely to be implemented any time remotely soon because it involves basically rebuilding our entire notifications system. I'm sure there's a feature request for it already, somewhere.

Comment: @animuson Ok thanks, I understand. I thought that something happened before the new "follow" option, I was certain of it.